# Consider switching to the bundled Java runtime message in Intellij on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: intellij-idea, raspberry-pi, intellij-14, raspberry-pi4

I have installed intelliJ by extracting ideaIC-2020.3.tar.gz file in /opt on my Raspberry pi 4. Whenever I run IntelliJ, I see the below message. There are some articles on this issue but non of them worked for me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Has anyone found a solution to this issue and can share the same?

Comment: Have you tried suggestions from this article: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under ?

Comment: yes, I have tried this link.

Comment: And JRE doesn't change?

Comment: No, if I check in Help > about

Comment: Please try to remove all IDE ralated data (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) and reinstall IDE. By default it should use bundled JRE.

Comment: This issue happens even when I do the fresh installation. Please note that this issue is specific to raspberry pi only. On my desktop there is no such issue.

Comment: Please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after changing JRE using "Choose Runtime" plugin.